# Error of conversion in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I created a database from the following flow chart: https://www.learncodinganywhere.com/learningmanagementsystem/links/07_DB/SQL_Drill.pdf

I am trying to retrieve the book title, borrower name, and borrower address in my 'Booksville' library branch where the due date is today. I created the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Title, b.[Name], b.[Address] as 'Due Today'
FROM 
    BORROWER b
JOIN 
    BOOK_LOANS bl ON b.CardNo = bl.CardNo
JOIN 
    LIBRARY_BRANCH lb ON lb.BranchId = bl.CardNo
JOIN
    BOOK bk ON bk.BookId = bl.BookId 
WHERE
    BranchName = 'Booksville' 
    AND DueDate = '10-25-2016'
```

But I get the following error message:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The conversion of the varchar value '5397270262193419' overflowed an int column.

Anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: We'll need the tables definition

Comment: could you upload the DB script, for creating its tables structure  ?

Comment: usually you get this error when comparing int fileds with char fields

Comment: maybe this line: on lb.BranchId=bl.CardNo   BranchId and CardNo ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there is information enought, but usually you get this error comparing numeric and alphanumeric fields.

I don't know the table schema but it seems there is mistake here:

```
on lb.BranchId=bl.CardNo
```

BranchId should match CardNo?

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you!! That did the trick. Was supposed to be on lb.BranchId=bl.BranchId